# Laravel 5.3 Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException Unauthenticated with graham-campbell/exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have problem with graham-campbell/exceptions and auth in Laravel 5.3 Error: `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException Unauthenticated.`. I read topic https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Exceptions/issues/80, but it couldnt help me end problem is still alive.

[throw new AuthenticationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sReA.png)

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (! is_null($user = $this->user())) {
        return $user;
    }

    throw new AuthenticationException; // I take error here
}
```

I need someone help, thank you to answer my question

Comment: please post your code .. and tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: in fact, i just want go in route with auth middelware. When i do it i take error `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException Unauthenticated`, but it must be redirect to `/login`

Comment: why did you do `$user = $this->user()` ... what were you thinking ?? This will always be `true` I guess.

Comment: It basic thing! I dont change code. In fact, i just install laravel, install graham-campbell/exceptions and use `php artisan make:auth`. Thats all. When i try go to /home (basic route for test auth middleware in 5.3) i got error.